# Update table with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following problem:

I have table:

```
TEST_TABLE
x_Id|y_Id
---------
   2|   7
   2|   8
   3|   7
   4|   7
   5|   8
```

I want remove record if x_Id has y_Id(7) and y_Id(8). And update y_Id to 7 if y_Id = 8 and y_Id(7) is not exist in the unique x_Id.

x_Id and y_Id is composite key.

Example of result:

```
TEST_TABLE
x_Id|y_Id
---------
   2|   7
   3|   7
   4|   7
   5|   7
```

Comment: Are you able to write a select where  x_Id has y_Id(7) and y_Id(8), and are just having a problem with the delete? If so, please post what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These queries do not use corelated subqueries (ones where they must be executed for every row of the outer query), so they should be quite efficient.

```
delete from test_table
where y_id = 8
and x_id in (select x_id from test_table where y_Id = 7);

update test_table set y_id = 7
where x_id in (select x_id from test_table where y_id = 8)
and x_id not in (select x_id from test_table where y_id = 7);
```

Comment: Have you EVER taken a look at execution plan in SQL Server? Examine your UPDATE statement and then check my alternative `UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET y_Id=7 FROM TEST_TABLE x WHERE y_Id=8 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE y_Id=7 AND x_Id=x.x_Id)`

Comment: `IN` clauses result in nested loops which could be prevented by using `EXISTS` clauses

Comment: To add one more thing: your second `WHERE` condition is unnecessary because you delete such rows satisfying this condition

Answer (score 5):

Delete duplicates (where for x_Id exists both y_Id's 7 and 8) and update all remaining y_Id where y_Id=8

```
DELETE FROM TEST_TABLE t1 WHERE y_Id=8 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE x_Id=t1.x_Id AND y_Id=7)
UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET y_Id=7 WHERE y_Id=8
```